# I accidently added rem unit to line-height value, It overlaps the margin why?

Tags: html, css, margin, line-height, css-rem

While aligning the text using css, I accidently added rem unit to line-height  (I think it shouldn't be added as of my knowledge)of the H3 element and this what happened.

[margin of the above P element comes in contact with h3 element below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M42Uz.png)

[also the margin of H3 element itself overlapping with H3 content. ]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUzqf.png)

```css
.step-number {
  font-size: 8.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.step-description {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.heading-tertiary {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="step-number">01</p>
<h3 class="heading-tertiary">Tell us what you like (and what not)</h3>
<p class="step-description">
Never again waste time thinking about what to eat! Omnifood AI will create a 100% personalized weekly meal plan just for you. It makes sure you get all the nutrients and vitamins you need, no matter what diet you follow!
</p>
```

I

After Removing the rem unit from the h3 element everthing works fine, but I just want to know what happens here. As this is my 1st question it may be in wrong format sorry for that.

Comment: Hi Nandhakumar and welcome to stackoverflow. Your font size is 3rem but your line height is 1.2rem. It overlaps because the font size is greater than the line height.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to be here. Hope I learn more from my bug, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font-size for h3 is 3rem but the line-height is 1.2rem. Whenever font-size is greater than the line-height, the text is bound to overlap.
So removing or reducing the line-height property will solve it.

```css
.step-number {
  font-size: 8.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.step-description {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.heading-tertiary {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="step-number">01</p>
<h3 class="heading-tertiary">Tell us what you like (and what not)</h3>
<p class="step-description">
Never again waste time thinking about what to eat! Omnifood AI will create a 100% personalized weekly meal plan just for you. It makes sure you get all the nutrients and vitamins you need, no matter what diet you follow!
</p>
```